# If I run two or more functions concurrently forever, do they access the same memory?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm using Praw, an API wrapper, to make a reddit bot. I am monitoring for and responding to both comments and posts. Praw has "streams" of new comments and new posts, so that I don't have to deal with stuff like making sure I don't respond to the same post twice. This is done with `for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():` and `for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():`. Both of these would loop endlessly, like creating two while(true) loops. What's the best way to monitor both streams concurrently? If I should use threading, will both threads be able to access the same variables?

For the curious: here's my code. https://github.com/kenblu24/procss-bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally yes, threads are able to access the whole process' memory. This is a feature which is consistent across programming languages.

Though multithreading in Python has severe limitations because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

If you can tolerate the slightly uglier code, you might try to process one element from the submissions, one from the comment etc. in turn, in a `while True` loop.

Comment: Can I create a conductor thread to pause threads and prevent memory access problems?

Comment: You should use the same patterns you'd use in another programming language, so having a conductor thread seems like overkill. You do have things like locks, and other synchronization mechanisms in Python, and must take care not to have deadlocks or corrupt state. It's just that a single thread at a time can hold the GIL, and can do Python work. If you have more than one core, then this means that even though other threads could be scheduled on those cores, they won't execute. In C#/Java/C++ you wouldn't have this issue, and could have multiple truly parallel threads of execution.